# Can't find default configuration "arch/arm/configs/bb.org_defconfig"

Tags: linux, kernel, beagleboneblack

I am facing issue in creating the configuring file for Linux Kernel source code.
I used this command to create configuration file.

```
sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- bb.org_defconfig
```

and I am getting following error:

> Can't find default configuration "arch/arm/configs/bb.org_defconfig"!

How to resolve this error?
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use omap2plus

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- omap2plus_defconfig
```